# Run commands from a text file through a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am attempting to write a script that will read through a text file, and then execute every line that begins with the word "run" or "chk" as a command. This is what I have thus far:

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=1
for i in $@
do
    while read -r line 
    do
    if [[ ${line:0:4} == "run " ]]
    then
        echo "Now running line $counter" 
        ${line:4:${#line}}
    elif [[ ${line:0:4} == "chk " ]]
    then
        echo "Now checking line $counter" 
        ${line:4:${#line}}
    elif [[ ${line:0:2} == "# " ]]
    then
        echo "Line $counter is a comment"
    else
        echo "Line $counter: '$line' is an invalid line"
    fi
    counter=$((counter+1))
    done<$i
done
```

However, when I feed it a text file with, for example the commands

```
run echo > temp.txt
```

It does not actually create a file called temp.txt, it just echoes "> temp.txt" back to the stdout. It also does a similar thing when I attempt to do something like

```
run program arguments > filename.txt
```

It does not put the output of the program in a file as I want, but it rather tries to treat the '>' as a file name.

I know this is a super specific and probably obvious thing, but I am very new to bash and all shell scripting.

Thanks

Comment: Most special characters are not processed when expanding variables. You need to use `eval` to do all the normal shell parsing.

Comment: would that make the substrings register as commands?

Comment: `eval` executes a string just as if it were a normal shell command.

Comment: `$@` needs to be enclosed in double quotes as `"$@"` to prevent word splitting and globbing.

Comment: Say one of the commands is an if statement that spans multiple lines. Is there a way to read it as one command instead of the while loop reading each line as a separate command?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `eval` to do all the normal shell parsing of the variable:

```
eval "${line:4}"
```

You also don't need `:${#line}`. If you leave out the length, it defaults to the rest of the string.

Comment: It might be useful commenting on what `eval` will do with the quoting and potential expansions on its arguments.

Comment: @Fred It just treats them exactly the same as if they were in the script itself.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thank you

Comment: @Barmar  I was not really clear with my comment.  The potential difficulty is when one (for any reason) tries to make up that string as part of a shell statement (i.e. a variable assignment).  It can be a bit frustrating when you are not knowledgeable enough.  It is not directly related to the question though.